# Why is Xamarin class inaccessible due to protection level?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, telephonymanager

I am trying to access the [telephony manager class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#inherited-methods) in Xamarin forms. I read up on the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) needed to be used in Xamarin.

While I am still a little confused on the types the constructor needs, and the reasoning, I put together a couple constructor args that I thought should work. I am getting an error that:

> TelephonyManager(IntPtr, JNIHandleOwnership) is inaccessible due to its protection level

How can this be? I can't control the protection level of the C# version of this Android class as far as I know.

```
using Android.Telephony;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CellularSignal
{
    public class MainActivityViewModel
    {
        public double getRSSI()
        {
            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            // **Intellisense error on line below**
            var t = new TelephonyManager(ptr, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe is These: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.runtime.jnihandleownership?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13

Comment: use `GetSystemService` to get a reference to `TelephonyManager`.  You don't instantiate it directly

Comment: Could you give me the syntax for that?

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context for it. Are You swiss knife? You are so good. You are a Native speaker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
TelephonyManager tpMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
```

where `mAppContext` is the current Activity that you are using in your app, if you are in one of its Fragments then you can get the activity from its Activity property.